# Connection closed by foreign host (postfix)

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

Tried to test my smtp server (centos server), I am using telet at centos

When I tried to test using code:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
```

> Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to 127.0.0.1. Escape character is '^]'.
>   220 smtp.mail.forexmart.eu ESMTP Postfix

But when I tried to test using:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

> Trying ::1...
>
> Connected to localhost.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.
>
> Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: this can be also problem with different configuration for IPv4 and IPv6, can you please provide `/var/log/mail.err` from the time of failed connection attempt

Answer (score 2):

localhost is resolver to IPv6 address **::1** (which is equivalent to IPv4 **127.0.0.1**) Your postfix maybe listen only on IPv4 address, To listen on IPv6 , you need to specify correct IPv6 address for `inet_interfaces` directive in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.

line should looks like `inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, [::1]`

Comment: That is equivalent to `inet_interfaces = loopback-only` which will do the same thing. In any case, checking the value of `inet_interfaces` is definitely a good first step here.